# Drupal 8 ReST EntityResource.php Allocates >200MB RAM on Post for Image

Tags: php, rest, post, drupal-8

Has anyone noticed that core/modules/rest/src/Plugin/rest/resource/EntityResource.php will try to allocate a huge amount of memory (over 200MB) at the end of the post() for a large variety of (>1MB) jpeg images?

It creates a memory exception at

> "$response - new ResourceResponse(NULL, 201);" to be exact.  It does
>   not throw the EntityStorageException.

Why might the post in EntityResource.php try to allocate so much memory when trying to post an image, which, by the way, DOES get saved into files/private?  What may `validate()` be doing?

Comment: If this is an issue with an API, you should pose this question to the API support.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a beta problem.  Gone in RC2.